# ARP when sent IP is wrong in every packet

Tags: ip, packet, arp

I have a question that I encountered in my Operating Systems exam today.
Given a process that "forges" the IP address in every sent packet (gives the wrong IP address), does the ARP work correctly?

I maintain that it doesn't, since the packet wouldn't know where to return the "ack".

Would love to hear your opinions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I maintain that it doesn't, since the packet wouldn't know where to return the "ack".

It is returned to the sender's MAC address, not IP address.

From [RFC 826](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc826.txt):

> When an address resolution packet is received, the receiving Ethernet
>   module gives the packet to the Address Resolution module which goes
>   through an algorithm similar to the following. Negative conditionals
>   indicate an end of processing and a discarding of the packet.

```
?Do I have the hardware type in ar$hrd?
Yes: (almost definitely)
  [optionally check the hardware length ar$hln]
  ?Do I speak the protocol in ar$pro?
  Yes:
    [optionally check the protocol length ar$pln]
    Merge_flag := false
    If the pair <protocol type, sender protocol address> is
        already in my translation table, update the sender
    hardware address field of the entry with the new
    information in the packet and set Merge_flag to true. 
    ?Am I the target protocol address?
    Yes:
      If Merge_flag is false, add the triplet <protocol type,
          sender protocol address, sender hardware address> to
      the translation table.
      ?Is the opcode ares_op$REQUEST?  (NOW look at the opcode!!)
      Yes:
    Swap hardware and protocol fields, putting the local
        hardware and protocol addresses in the sender fields.
    Set the ar$op field to ares_op$REPLY
    Send the packet to the (new) target hardware address on
        the same hardware on which the request was received.
```

### What this means?

[ARP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) is return addressed using MACs, although IP addresses can also be included in the Sender protocol address (SPA) field of the packet. This means that although the sender IP address (SPA) is spoofed, there is no mention of the Sender hardware address (SHA) being spoofed in your question.

This means that the sender *will* receive the ARP replies and ARP will function (from the point of view of the sending machine). However, as the ARP packets contain a spoofed SPA, the target machines (and possibly other devices on the network) will associate the sender as having that IP address, enabling a successful [ARP poisoning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARP_spoofing) attack:

> e.g. Linux ignores unsolicited replies, but on the other hand uses seen requests from other machines to update its cache.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will know where to return the ack to, because the sender sends his MAC address and this what matters. Yet I think it won't work because the receiver will change his ARP table according to the MAC&IP he got from the sender. (this is a trivial optimization).